# How to translate properties with i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

How I normally use i18next to translate stuff

```
<Translation>{(t) => <span>{t('key')}</span>}</Translation>
```

But I'm not too sure how to translate properties such as title value "Dashboard" in the following line

```
 <NavExpandable title="Dashboard" isExpanded>
```

I haven't been able to find a solution yet and I can't believe I'm the only one who has this problem.

Comment: `<NavExpandable title={<AnyJSX here="this is just an inline example" />} isExpanded>`

Comment: There's probably cleaner approach with i18next, but just know that you can use JSX inline in props value.

Comment: Do you mean something like: <NavExpandable title={<Translation>{(t) => <span>{t('key')}</span>}</Translation>} isExpanded> ? If so, it doesn't work as it returns an object.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I've also tried doing something like this: {i18next.t('key')} but it just renders "key".

Comment: Are you using react-i18next? [Its documentation](https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start) shows multiple way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: The reason why it fails when a prop is an object is because it should take a `node` prop-type instead of a `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was using `import { Translation } from 'i18next';` instead of `import { Translation } from 'react-i18next';`